# Updating Role description (entity framework / LINQ)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity

Mates, I want to update a role description using my application
I don´t know what is the better way to connect to the database and run a UPDATE statement.

Would it be Entity Framework? LINQ? None of this 2 options..

Please, suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not Linq ..well yes linq, but linq is the querying framework where as entity framework is the object relational mapper. So Both actually. You could do this in various other ways but those two technologies work very well together from my experience.

In Visual studio you would create a new ADO.NET project template which you then hook up to your database. and then you can update the tables and do a whole bunch of stuff. Linq is build into .NET so technically you can query any objects using linq ( which makes it so much fun ) and because your entity is an object you just reference it ( first declare it ) and then play with it

```
FooModel foo = new FooModel(); // Entity
var fooQuery = from _ in foo.DescriptionTable // Linq query
               where _.Description == SelectedDesc // table selection query
               select _;

foo.Add(fooQuery); // add to database
foo.SaveChanges(); // save changes
```

Something like that. There is a bit more to it that would project specific but you would have to give more details.

It is most certainly worth learning both technologies and have doubt you will find them very useful. Both can get very complex but for what you need it for you just need the basics down and then you can explore from there.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that Entity Framework would be currently the best solution for you. Not only it is strongly supported by Microsoft (well Silverlight was as well) but:

If you start with it, you can use designer. It's graphical UI will guide you when generating the model (based on database) or generating the database schema when starting with model.
Read some tutorials abut it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907

And later take a look how to use some more profesionla techniques as Repository pattern or unit of work

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application